# python: SyntaxError: invalid syntax Expected member name after "."

Tags: python

I'm using `argparse` to parse the parameters, but when I get `args.global`, a strange error appears, I don't know where I did it wrong

```py
...

parser.add_argument('-u','--update', action='store_true', default=None)
parser.add_argument('-g','--global', action='store_true', default=None)
args = parser.parse_args()

...

if args.update:
    print(args)
    print( args.global )
    print( args.update )
```

```sh
$ python ./anpm.py -g -u
  File "./anpm.py", line 67
    print( args.global )
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the error given by vscode

[image]

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.6.8
```

Comment: `global` is a Python keyword, you can't use it as an attribute name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`global` is a keyword in Python (as are `if`, `while`, etc.) and you cannot use these as attribute names, which means they also don't work in a `NameSpace` object.

More on that here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

However, you can still access these values if you need to use these names:

```
my_args = vars(args)
print(my_args['global'])
```

This works because it doesn't use the reserved word, instead it just uses a string (containing the reserved word) to access its value.

If you only need access once, or infrequently and you don't want to keep the `vars()` result around, you can also just:

```
print(vars(args)['global'])
```

Comment: ... or rename the corresponding option.

Comment: ```    if args['del']:
TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: After `args.global`, I encountered `args.del` again. I think this is a problem caused by a design flaw in the python interpreter.

Comment: @tripleee - obviously, but the answer already states "if you need to use these names"

Comment: @januwa - same solution: don't try to access `args.del`, `del` is a reserved word. Use `vars(args)['del']` or alternatively, `getattr(args, 'del')`. Naming attributes using keywords is just a really bad idea and `argparse` making use of `NameSpace` objects sadly causes this conflict for command-line parameters as well, where you may be unable to avoid these keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getattr`:

```
print(getattr(args, 'global'))
```

This would get the attribute `global`.

Answer (score 1):

## Global Explanation

Global is a reserved keyword in python that is used to declare a variable globally inside the functional scope.
Example:

```
def p():
    global x
    x=23
p()
print(x)
//returns 23
```

## Keywords and example

A keyword can't be used as an argument or a variable in python. you can have other examples like

```
yield=23
return=34
pass=34
continue=23
.....
```

All these make an error.

## Solution

Try changing the name from global to __global or _global or something like this.